# Authenticating with multiple Facebook apps simultaneously on mobile

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, oauth

We are building an SDK to be used by other developers. Our product requires registration and we're planning to offer a "Sign in with Facebook" option.

From reading out the Facebook documentation online for this, seems we'd need to perform the following steps:

1. Set up a "Facebook App"
2. Users registering with the "Facebook" option will approve this app and authenticate with Facebook.

The issue is -- what if the app that uses our SDK is already defined in Facebook, and the user is currently authenticated (has a token associated with that app id) ?

Is it possible to be authenticated with 2 different apps at the same time (i.e: hold 2 authentication tokens that are associated to different Facebook apps).

*The environment is Android/iOS (mobile apps, not browser based)

Answer (score 1):

As developer of an SDK that uses Facebook you are not the one to 'Set up a "Facebook App"'. The users of your SDK have to do it themselves. So each app made with your SDK will be associated with another "Facebook app". As developer of the SDK all you have to do I think is give the option to fill in their app id.